# Revert folder back into package

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, package

When I opened Eclipse all packages that I had within my res source folder were changed into folders. The code that I created to automatically load Images and other files no longer works. Is there anyway to change the folders back into packages? Here is a picture of my problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg1PG.jpg - Image

The images folder is still correctly displaying as a package, which is what I need. What I want is for every other folder (Girl, Bat, Death, etc) to be a package as well. Thank you.

Comment: try removing and re-adding the folder from the build path (project properties)

Comment: I tried doing this but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something is not configured in your project configuration files. In package explorer select the drop down arrow all the way to the right of the package explorer view, in that drop down menu select filters. In the dialog that appears uncheck *.resources so you can see your project config files.

Start by opening the .classpath file in that file make sure you see this entry

```
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="res"/>
```

If the kind is set to a different value other than src that could be the problem.

Secondly open build.properties and make sure that you have an entry that looks like this so it includes your res as source code

> source.. = src/,res

Lastly if that does not work, right click on the project to get the context menu go to new -> source folder call it something else like res2. Once you have that folder created drag and drop your existing resources from your existing res folder into res2 and see if they show up as packages assuming they do, delete your original res folder, then right click on res2 and refactor the name back to res

If you're still stuck after that than you've got a mystery on your hands, last resort would be to create a new Java project and copy resources over.